# I want insert information to database automatic in date 30 from all month (without submit) [PHP]

Tags: php, mysql

In the following code, it only works when the user clicks the page, I don't want this, But I want in the 30th day of every month to insert information automatically to MySQL.
I want an example that does the same idea mentioned.

مع هذا الكود الإضافة لا تعمل الا اذا قام المستخدم بضغط ع الصفحة , و هذا ما لا اريده , كل ما اريده هو انه في 30 من الشهر الفلاني اضافة معلومات في قواعد البيانات بشكل اوتوماتيكي

AND Thnx و شكرا

```
$today = date("d");
    $month = date("m");
    $history = date("Y-m-d") ;
    if($today == 30){
    $cheak = "select * from total where EmployeeID = '$id_coo' AND  MONTH(TotalDate) = '$month'";
    $run_cheak = mysqli_query($connect,$cheak);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($run_cheak) > 0) {
     echo '';
    }else{
        @$insert_end = "insert into  total  (TotalCost,TotalSave,TotalDate,EmployeeID) values  ('$sum','$total','$history','$id_coo')";
        @$run_insert_delte = mysqli_query($connect,$insert_end);


        header("Location: budgetResult.php"); /* Redirect browser */
    }
    }
```

Comment: I am having a hard time reading the question. I suspect english it not first language perhaps? By 30 date, does that mean 30 days?

Comment: What about February?

Comment: yeah it not my first , every moth have 30 day e.g 24/12/2017 some moth have more than 30 day i just want in day 30 php insert information to table_name auto without click any link , i hope you understand me T_T

Comment: On UNIX (and mac), you can use `cron` to schedule tasks. If you write your script so it can be run from the command line, then you can write a cron task to run that job at the proper times. I'm sure there is a Windows equivalent as well.

Comment: its look like so match hard , im so noob in code . i just wanna learn

Answer (score 0):

If its only limited to the DB you can use Event Scheduler like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT event1
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' MONTH
STARTS '2018-01-30 00:00:00'
DO 
BEGIN
 -- your code
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

and then run

```
   SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;
```

-But where are you geting the input ID from?
or  do you want to run it for all records?